# Howto replace different values with tags in string?

Tags: python

I have string:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor [mytag]something[/mytag]sit amet, ipsum [mytag]something else[/mytag]a laoreet ultricies
```

and I want to get values "something" and "something else" and replace it.

How to do it?

Comment: i don't know why this question got a up-vote! it doesn't say what's the expected output. And no sample code from the OP.

Comment: It's post. I want to replace tags [img] [/img] with <img src="..." />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions is the way to go.

```
import re
s = 'Lorem ipsum dolor [mytag]something[/mytag]sit amet, ipsum [mytag]something else[/mytag]a laoreet ultricies'
print re.sub(r'\[mytag\](.+?)\[/mytag\]', r'<img src="\1">', s)
```

Comment: Your solution works, but Python bbcode module is more elegant :-)

Comment: @Yohann: I agree, but installing third-party modules can be inappropriate for the OP.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [bbcode module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bbcode) :

```
# Using the default parser.
import bbcode
html = bbcode.render_html(text)
```

Optionnal because i think there is already [img] :

```
# Installing simple formatters.
parser = bbcode.Parser()
parser.add_simple_formatter('img', '<img src="%(value)" />')
```